# Covers of $S^1 \vee S^1$ are directed 2-colored graphs

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I understand that every directed 2-colored graph defines a cover for $S^1 \vee S^1$. But how would one go about showing the other direction, that $\textbf{every}$ cover of $S^1 \vee S^1$ is a directed 2-colored graph?

Comment: Do you know that a covering space of a graph is itself a graph?